# Implement recursion using foldl in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

given the below code

```
pair :: [String] -> [(String,String)]
pair [] = []
pair (x:xs)= zip [x] xs ++ pair xs
```

how could I rewrite it using Fold to avoid repetition ?

Comment: Anything you tried already?

Comment: I tried this f= foldl (++) [] which a list of list of pair and return a list of pair

Comment: Cool. It's good to put in your code in your question, so others know what might be causing the issue/error. Can you also put in what output you expect? Your version with `fold` returns a different result than your original code.

Comment: If by "avoid repetition" you mean write less code you can even avoid using `fold` and try something like: `zip xs (tail xs)`

Comment: You can use `foldr` when your recursive branch for `x:xs` depends only on `x` and `f xs`. Yours also depends on `xs`. (One could use a more sophisticated fold, and achieve that anyway, but it would not be readable)

Comment: @DavideSpataro Or even shorter, `pair = zip <*> tail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fold is going to be a bit messy for this particular problem because your folding function depends upon the previously visited elements in the list, with a two-value list minimum. And since folding visits elements one at a time, you have to decide what to do when there's only one element in the list.

Here is an example that creates a dummy element for the singleton list case and discards it with `init`.

```haskell
pair :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
pair = init . foldr f []
  where
    f x acc =
      case acc of
        [] -> [(x, "discarded")]
        z@(y:_) -> (x, fst y) : z
```

If you're tasked with learning about folds, take a minute to understand why we have to handle it in such an unsatisfactory way. Otherwise, if you're looking to do this in the least amount of code, see @DavideSpataro's answer above of `zip xs (tail xs)`.